# How do I delete a MongoDB document with pymongo when the object id is nan?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo database. There is a document that exists in a collection where the object ID field is null. I would like to remove this collection from the database entirely

```
records = list(db.MyCollection.find())
for record in records:
    if pd.isnull(record['_id']):
        print(record)

{'_id': nan, 'other_data': nan}
```

I have tried:

```
db.Sample.delete_one({'_id': 'nan'})
```

and also:

```
db.Sample.delete_one({'_id': np.nan})
```

Though neither of these remove the collection. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with None?

Comment: @Euclides Good suggestion, unfortunately that does not seem to work either. Unless I am missing something else entirely and not dropping documents correctly at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `null` it's `nan`, which is actually represented as [`float('nan')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan):

```
db.Sample.delete_one({ '_id': float('nan') })
```